# Facebook Login API not working on localhost

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I am able to interact with the Facebook Login API from my hosted web server, however when I change these settings to the localhost server I receive the message below. I have also tried adding a port number (80) but with no success. I have researched this question here on SO but it seems that I am missing something.

App Domains: `localhost` 
Site URL: `http://localhost/`

Erorr: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration....

Answer (score 1):

Add the port you are using at your localhost and you will get, you are looking for ....
like http://localhost:62024/